# Определение клика по inline элементу в telegram боте

Tags: php, telegram-bot, inline

Бот выводит инлайн список

[image: inline]

После клика по любому из элементов отправляется текст. Мне надо определить, по какому из элементов инлайн списка кликнул пользователь. Если это сделано в самом боте, то проблем нет, я получаю данные сообщения. А если это сделано в стороннем чате где нет бота, то как я могу отследить что нажат элемент например Test2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, поможет информация с официального сайта, на странице [Inline Bots](https://core.telegram.org/bots/inline).

**Получение обратной связи**

Чтобы знать, какой из предложенных вариантов выбран пользователем в inline режиме, отправьте **@Botfather** команду `/setinlinefeedback`. Сделав это, вы начнете получать информацию о выборе пользователей.

---

**Collecting feedback**

To know which of the provided results your users are sending to their chat partners, send **@Botfather** the `/setinlinefeedback` command. With this enabled, you will receive updates on the results chosen by your users.